# JPA entities, circular references and toString()

Tags: java, jpa

Often one would have entity graphs where a relation is mapped in both ways, eg.

```
class Home {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "home")
  Set<Room> rooms;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Home [id=" + id + ", rooms=" + rooms + "]";
  }
}

class Room {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Home home;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Room [id=" + id + ", home=" + home + "]";
  }
}
```

Said so, if we produce the toString method using the IDE's automatisms we may cause inadvertently a deep recursion in the toString() method, because Home will print Rooms and each Room will in turn print its Home.

Is there any elegant way (specifically for debug purpose) to print graphs of objects in a clear, toString-like way without having to pay attention in implementing the toString() method to avoid loops?

Comment: Just print the `home.id` instead of the entire home.

Comment: Doing anything without paying attention is usually a bad idea. Do pay attention. Navigating through associations in a toString() method is usually a bad idea, because it will cause an exception as soon as the association is lazy and the entity is detached.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the following with Apache Commons Lang

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

This will give you a reflexive representation of the object. This way you could implement a formatter which would traverse the object graph and pretty print the output but not have to worry about managing individual addition/removal of properties.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the problem related to circular references in toString method objects!